# Google Cloud Endpoint execute async code in endpoints

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, firebase-authentication, google-compute-engine

I am trying to authenticate client token created by Firebase authentication library in Android in GCE endpoint.

The guide of how to do this can be found [here](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/firebase-talk/165pe7ge6x/firebase-gae-firebase-auth)

Basically I need to call this code snippet from the end point (i.e. server backend code not android code).

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(idToken)
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FirebaseToken>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FirebaseToken decodedToken) {
            String uid = decodedToken.getUid();
            // ...
        }
});
```

Let say I want to execute that code and return the user to android client code. How should I do that?

This is my sample code that does not make sense. But it demonstrate what I want to do!

```
@ApiMethod(name = "serverAuth")
public MyUser serverAuth(@Named("token") String token) {
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(token)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FirebaseToken>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(FirebaseToken decodedToken) {
                    String uid = decodedToken.getUid();
                    String email = decodedToken.getEmail();
                    String name = decodedToken.getName();
                    Map<String, Object> claims = decodedToken.getClaims();

                    String claimString = "";

                    for (Object claim : claims.values()) {
                        claimString += claims.toString();
                    }

                    MyUser user = new MyUser(uid, email, name, claimString);
                    //How to return this user?

                }
            });

    //This is compile error since user varriable does not exist here    
    return user;

}
```

I have google search how to execute async code in GCE endpoints. But getting nowhere with that. What I get is something about code execution that is blocking until done and then return the user.  But how to code so that async code as above become blocking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**CountDownLatch** is the magic class you need. It will let you wait till the OnSuccessListener is actually completed.

Adapt your method this way: (I removed the steps that lead to MyUser's creation in order to focus on important points.)

```
@ApiMethod(name = "serverAuth")
public MyUser serverAuth(@Named("token") String token) {
    final List<MyUser> users = new ArrayList<>();
    final CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(1);
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(token)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FirebaseToken>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(FirebaseToken decodedToken) {
                    // ... init uid, email, name and claimString
                    users.add(new MyUser(uid, email, name, claimString));
                    cdl.countDown();
                }
            });
    try {
        cdl.await(); // This line blocks execution till count down latch is 0
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {

    }
    if (users.size() > 0) {
        return users.get(0);
    } else {
        return null ;
    }
}
```

This is the basic version of what you need. IMHO, it requires 2 more improvements :

- You should also take the **possibility of failure** into account :

  ```
  FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(token)
  .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FirebaseToken>() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(FirebaseToken decodedToken) {
          cdl.countDown();
      }
  }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
      @Override
      public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
          // log error, ...
          cdl.countDown();
      }
  });
  ```
- You should also take the possibility that none of the listeners are called. In this situation your method will never return. To avoid that, you can set a **timeout** on the await() method :

  ```
  try {
       // This line blocks execution till count down latch is 0
       // or after 30 seconds.
      cdl.await(30l, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  } catch (InterruptedException ie) {

  }
  ```

That's it. Hope this may help.

Comment: Thanks! It works. However I get error that user variable is final and can not be set. I work around it by promoting user to class private variable. This is just a test code so being messy is allowed. But I am still interested to hear about a better way to do user variable as final variable.

Comment: Yes you are right - assigning final variable is forbidden. Sorry for the not fully tested sample. But I think that using a class variable is not the best workaround. I would rather use a "container" or "wrapper". See my updated answer.